# apt-get and -d option (download only) - what about packages to be removed?

Tags: apt

What does the `-d` option of `apt-get` do when there are packages to be removed (I got the list of actions by the `--simulate` option)?

Comment: what is your question?  If you are apt-get removing packages, -d makes it do nothing.

Answer (score 3):

If you specify `-d` to `apt-get`, it'll just download packages, nothing else. It won't install or remove anything, even if your command implicitly removes some packages. For  example,
 if you "install" (with `-d`) package that requires removing another package; this is the case with Apache workers (and many other packages too).